# How to rename program group in an Inno Setup update installation?

Tags: inno-setup

Our Inno Setup based installer creates a program group and included the major version number in its name, e.g. "*Foo Bar 2*". This was initially done by the directives

```
[Setup]
; Note: there is no AppId 
...
DefaultGroupName={#AppName} {#AppVersion}
UsePreviousGroup=yes
```

Inno Setup remembers this name and reuses it. So for our upcoming new release, the major number is now ***3*** but the program group is not updated to "*Foo Bar **3***" and remains at "*Foo Bar 2*".

I have unsuccessfully tried removing `{group}` via `[InstallDelete]`. Deleting the group folder or renaming it also does not work for me.

Based on Bill's hint, I would like to know how I can strip the version number of the program group during an update installation.

If the user changed the name of the group and it does no longer match the default name, I'm not going to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to code the in Pascal Script. Something like this:

```
#define AppName "My Program"

[Setup]
DefaultGroupName={#AppName}
```

```pascal
[Code]
var
  GroupPath: string;

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  GroupName: string;
begin
  if not WizardForm.NoIconsCheck.Checked then
  begin
    GroupName := RemoveBackslashUnlessRoot(WizardForm.GroupEdit.Text);
    if GroupName = '{#AppName} 2' then
    begin
      GroupPath := AddBackslash(ExpandConstant('{autoprograms}')) + GroupName;
      WizardForm.GroupEdit.Text := '{#SetupSetting("DefaultGroupName")}';
      Log(Format('Old version Start menu group "%s" (path "%s") was found, ' + 
                 'it will be deleted and new icons will be created in "%s"', [
                 GroupName, GroupPath, WizardForm.GroupEdit.Text]));
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssInstall then
  begin
    if GroupPath <> '' then
    begin
      Log(Format('Deleting old Start menu group from folder "%s"', [GroupPath]));
      if DelTree(GroupPath, True, True, True) then Log('Successfully deleted')
        else Log('Error while deleting');
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Use with care. Calling `DelTree` (particularly with Administrator permissions) can cause disaster, if the path is calculated incorrectly. You might consider deleting specific individual icon files only and then the empty (if) folder instead.

---

*Though note that start menu groups shall not be used as per Windows guidelines since like Windows 7. So the correct solution would be to remove the group instead of renaming it.*

Comment: Deleting the old program group folder works but it is recreated during the update installation. Inno Setup seems to remember the old group name. That's why it initially appeared as if the folder was not deleted.
I found, that setting `UsePreviousGroup` to `No` will make Inno Setup use the new default group name. I also skip the `wpSelectProgramGroup` page on update installations and only delete the folder, if it still starts with the base default app name.